# In Qtp on printing value in local sheet column from global sheet only the last row value is getting priint

Tags: excel, datatable, automation, qtp

```
systemUtil.run "iexplore",datatable.Value(4,1)

datatable.value(5,1)=Browser("Google").Page("Google").WebElement("India").GetROProperty("innertext")
a=datatable.GetSheet("Global").GetParameter("result").Value
datatable.value(2,2)=a

browser("Google").Close
datatable.Export "C:\Users\arajput\Desktop\qtp.xlsx"
```

I want to print the country below the logo google i.e india, uk etc by passing different url in a new sheet column. I have passed different url in the global sheet it works fine on outputting the country name in global sheet but on getting the same value in local sheet i.e the new sheet it only displays the last url value only one row is returned as it is overwrite the previous one

Comment: Can you put the entire code to understand your query better and provide any help?

Answer (score 1):

Wow... I took a look at the code you've posted so far, and it's very confusing.

You're using a mix of index numbers and names for your sheets and parameters...  For exmple, first you fire off iexplore using a URL contained in "field #4" of the global sheet... I can't tell what that parameter is called, I just know it's column #4.

Then, you store the innertext value of an object identified by the Test Object called "India" into column #5 of the global sheet.  Again, I can't tell when that parameter is called.

Next, you want to put some data into a variable called "a"... but, to get that data, you're pulling the .value of a parameter called "result" which is also a column on the global sheet...

So, a problem starts here - I can't tell what the column number of "result" is... it could be column 5, which is where you just put the innertext of "India" ...   but it could be column 6, or something else which would be different.  The point here is there could be a subtle bug that's hard to find here.  or it could be fine. I can't tell.

Next, you immediately put the value from a back into the datatable into column 2 of sheet 2... Again, I have no information about what that parameter is called, or even what sheet 2 is called.  (One thing I DO know is that QTP will insist on sheet 2 being the datasheets that belongs to the first Action that was created...  but that may be irrelevant)

After all that, you export the sheet to a file.

This is all very confusing, but this is what you've given us to work with.

Here are some things to check.

1) are you changing the CurrentRow of the datatable?  You might have a situation where you are changing the CurrentRow of the global table, but not the local table.  Check to make sure that you are setting the CurrentRow of both tables before reading or writing data to those tables.

2) I noticed that you are reading data from a WebElement object called "India"...  but you also described that you might expect to find "uk" in that object...  So, perhaps the object called "India" should be called "Country"...  Anyway, you should check to make sure the Test Object description of that WebElement can properly identify that object even when it is not showing "India" as it's innertext.

3) I also noticed your question talks about "priint" (I assume you mean print), but your example code doesn't actually Print anything.  You just export the whole sheet, and we can't tell why "only the last row value is getting priint"

Answer (score 0):

It took some time to understand your question, i hope below answer can help you.

It is always good practice to point tables with its name, not with Index(ex: "Global" instead of '1' and "SomeSheet" instead of '2'. same applies to column names also)

```
glbRwCount=Datatable.GetSheet("Global").GetRowCount
For i=1 to glbRwCount
 Datatable.GetSheet("Global").SetCurrentRow(i)
 systemUtil.run "iexplore",datatable.Value(4,"Global")
 Datatable.value(5,"Global")=Browser("Google").Page("Google").WebElement("India").GetROProperty("innertext")
 a=Datatable.GetSheet("Global").GetParameter("result").Value
 Datatable.GetSheet("Action1").SetCurrentRow(i)
 Datatable.value(2,"Action1")=a    
 Browser("Google").Close     
Next
Datatable.Export "C:\Users\arajput\Desktop\qtp.xlsx"
```